# cudaMemset fail to obtain an argument

Tags: c, memory, cuda, gpu

I'm working on [a quiz on Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs344/lessons/86719951/concepts/907138050923) and encounter a really weird problem:

```
#include "reference_calc.cpp"
#include "utils.h"

void your_histogram_and_prefixsum(const float* const d_logLuminance,
                                  unsigned int* const d_cdf,
                                  float &min_logLum,
                                  float &max_logLum,
                                  const size_t numRows,
                                  const size_t numCols,
                                  const size_t numBins)
{
    float* an_array;
    cudaMalloc(&an_array, sizeof(float) * 1);

    cudaMemset(an_array, 0, 1);
    //cudaMemset(an_array, d_logLuminance[0], 1);

}
```

This program do nothing but allocate (`cudaMalloc`) some memory for an array and set(`cudaMemset`) it's first sub index to 0.

It goes well until I change

```
cudaMemset(an_array, 0, 1);
```

to

```
cudaMemset(an_array, d_logLuminance[0], 1);
```

Program compiles but fail:

> We are unable to execute your code. Did you set the grid and/or block size correctly?

I don't know why I couldn't pass `d_logLuminance[0]` to `cudaMemset`.

Could somebody help me?

Comment: If such a small change is a problem, the obvious first step should be to check the parameters the function expects. After 2s with google I found this signature: `cudaError_t cudaMemset (void *devPtr, int value, size_t count);` 
And you can see clearly that second parameter is an `int` while you throw a `float` at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in cudaMemset is a byte value, not a word value, ie. the same as in the C standard library memset.

As you are discovering, cudaMemset works like the C standard library memset. Quoting from the documentation:

```
cudaError_t cudaMemset  (   void *      devPtr,
                            int         value,
                            size_t      count    
                        )
```

Fills the first count bytes of the memory area pointed to by devPtr with the constant byte value value.

So value is a byte value. If you do something like:

```
int *devPtr;
cudaMalloc((void **)&devPtr,number_bytes);
const int value = 5;
cudaMemset(devPtr,value,number_bytes);
```

what you are asking to happen is that each byte of devPtr will be set to 5. If devPtr was a an array of integers, the result would be each integer word would have the value 84215045. This is probably not what you had in mind.